# R running from command line populating MySQL database

Tags: r, command-line, rmysql

I have written some R code that works perfectly and creates a dataframe which I then append to a pre-existing table within my MySQL database using RmySQL and the following line:

```
dbWriteTable(con, 'betfair7', final, append=TRUE)
```

All works fine.

However, when i try to automate the script using a .bat file or run it from command line using the following line:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.13.1\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave "c:\my_script.R"
```

it seems to work, in that it pauses and seems to process but the MySQL database is not updated. This either suggests it hasn't run successfully or it's not making the correct connection to the database in CMD mode?

Comment: Do you send a commit statement to the database before the script terminates?

Comment: What's a commit statement?

Comment: You are using a very old version of R